# run kivy in notepad++ and always got wrong in <ScatterTextWidget>

Tags: kivy

There's always an error in line ' ScatterTextWidget: '(the one with '<>'). I dont know why.

Here is my code:

```
    import kivy

    from kivy.app import App
    from kivy.uix.scatter import Scatter
    from kivy.uix.label import Label
    from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
    from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
    from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput

    class ScatterTextWidget(BoxLayout):
        pass

    class MyApp(App):
        def build(self):
           return ScatterTextWidget()

    <ScatterTextWidget>：
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            TextInput:
                id: my_text
                font_size = 200
                size_hint_y: None
                height: 200
                text: 'what fuck'
            FloatLayout:
                Scatter:
                    Label:
                        Text: my_text.text
                        font_size: 150



if __name__== '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is kv syntax, not python syntax. You can't put them both in the same file unless you put the kv in a string (e.g. `kv = ''' ... '''`) and load it with `kivy.lang.Builder.load_string`.